# How to ignore all fields which are empty in pic column?

Tags: php, sql

All with empty fields in pic column should be ignored. (Even Name/Address shouldn't be visible)

```
$sql = "SELECT pic, title, address FROM 
 WP_2344432";  
$result = $conn->query($sql);  
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of 
   each row  
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
     echo '<br> <img src="'.$row['pic'].'"><br>Name: '. 
     $row['title']. '<br>Coordinates: ' . $row['address'] . 
      '<br>';  
   }  
 } else {
   echo "0 results"; 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a detailed example of input data with the results you get vs the results you would like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `pic` column contains null then add `WHERE pic IS NULL` to your select. If it is simply empty then use `WHERE pic = ''`.

```
$sql = "SELECT pic, title, address FROM WP_2344432 WHERE pic IS NOT NULL";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT pic, title, address FROM WP_2344432 WHERE pic != ''";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I solved this with COALSE. $sql = "SELECT pic, title, address, map_id, category FROM wp_2344432 WHERE COALESCE(pic, '') != '' ORDER BY id DESC";